# Adding external library for 32bit and 64bit in android studio

Tags: java, android, 64-bit, x86-64, 32-bit

I am trining to to add a library for both architect 32bit and 64bit as it is available for both separately. I am using these library.

**For 32bit:**

```
implementation project(path: ':xwalk_core_library-21.51.546.7')
```

**For 64bit:**

```
implementation project(path: ':xwalk_core_library-21.51.546.7-64bit')
```

it is available at the link below:
https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/21.51.546.7/

I have included `.aar` files for bot 32 and 64 bit and
It is working in the debug mode for both 32 and 64 bit architectures
But unfortunately, I am getting this error in release mode.

> Program type already present: org.xwalk.core.XWalkUpdater$ForegroundListener